# How to equalize the histogram

Tags: algorithms, image-processing

I'm reading the *Digital Image Processing Using Matlab 2nd Edition* of page *81*. There is a question that confuses me. As you see in the following passage

[image]

But I don't understand why the probability density will be `0` and `1`. For example this image:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I can plot its PDFs histogram :
[image: Mathematica graphics]

Then I can plot its CDF :
[image: Mathematica graphics]

It is clearly not `0` and `1`。

Comment: This property holds for the transformed values, not the original ones.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Please note that is $P_s(s)$

Comment: After having transformed the PDF should become uniform.

Comment: @mathreadler But the transormed formula just is an *integral transform*

Comment: Yes, but over which *domain* are we integrating?

Comment: @mathreadler I'm sorry,I'm confused still.Could you give more detail explaination for it?

Comment: I will see if I can explain it better. Maybe later.